# Iframe javascript Keylogger

Tags: javascript, keyloggers

Is it possible for a website to have a javascript keylogger and also contain an iframe that goes to a "client" site.

- Can the the JS log all key strokes done on the client site?
- Can the (host) iframe be invisible or 0 x 0 in size?
- Can the "client" site detect and bust the iframe?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can embed a .js file using a Stored XSS to perform the remote keylogging.
Using Ajax, it should be easy to do the remote logging. Have a look at the Javascript Keylogger here. http://code.google.com/p/javascript-keylogger

Setting the iframe width and height to zero answers the second question

```
<iframe src="attacker.com/log.php" width="0" height="0">
```

What you are asking in the 3rd question is frame busting. There are techniques to do that,
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking#Defending_with_Frame_Breaking_Scripts

Comment: But frame busting is not reliable, if you have a XSS vulnerability, as you can, in IE8 and Chrome, use the XSS filter to destroy it.

Comment: For almost every mitigation whether on the OS level or the webapp level there is always a way to bypass when coupled with other vulnerabilities.

Comment: My point was, don't think that because you're using this technique, you're home free, and don't have to care about XSS vulnerabilities.