# Can an embedded 3rd party JS script access or keystroke log an iFrame's content

Tags: javascript, vulnerability, iframe

Say there is a web page with two 3rd party javascript URL scripts embedded in it. One creates a support chat window and the other creates an iFrame within which a user enters payment information into a form.

If the support chat script was compromised and could it get access the payment information? e.g keystroke logging on the page or directly accessing the form information

Comment: Welcome to the community. Have you looked into https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23398/iframe-javascript-keylogger ? You might also find this interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2up8J9dErHI

Comment: Modern browsers will isolate JS scopes to same-domain.  If the parent/iframe have different domains you can't access it.  (The exception is if the iframe explicitly posts messages that the parent can listen to:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage )  Presumably the payment info iframe's src is set to a different domain than the parent or chat iframe.  It's likely a payment iframe has additional sandbox settings as well.